# The type of the third parameter in preg_match_all() when no matches are found

Tags: php

I'm using `preg_match_all()` in my project to find matches in a given string. For example:

```
preg_match_all( $pattern, $subject, $matches, $flags );
```

If matches are found, the `$matches` parameter will be a multidimensional array of matches ordered according to `$flags`.

If matches weren't found, what type would `$matches` be? Would it still be an array, albeit an empty array, or would it be something else such as `false` or `null`?

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Why did you not try out? Just var_dump() $matches or prove it against different values like false or null with `===`.

Comment: This sounds like it should be [very easy to check](http://ideone.com/Cy7HWM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$matches will be an array containing an empty sub-array. It's something that you can easily test yourself.

```
<?php

preg_match_all('/O/', 'foo', $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually `$matches` is not empty, `$matches[0]` is empty.

Comment: It's empty, more or less. but I've edited to reflect this change.

Answer (score 1):

You will not get an empty array, but an array of one or several empty arrays, depending on the capturing groups in your regex. See the difference:

```
preg_match_all('/foo/', 'bar', $matches);
print_r($matches);
Array
(
    [0] => Array ( )
)

preg_match_all('/(f)oo/', 'bar', $matches);
print_r($matches);
Array
(
    [0] => Array ( )
    [1] => Array ( )
)
```

Comment: Nice catch with the presence of capturing groups giving a slightly different empty response.

Answer (score 0):

A simple test will show you this:

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9]/", "Hello World", $matches);
var_dump($matches);

array(1) { 
  [0]=> array(0) { 
  } 
}
```